# How to Calculate date from only the day of the month?

Tags: vb.net, date, time

I am wondering if you can help me with a date problem I have.

I have a text box called txtDay where you enter the day of the month relating to the date of the message you are sending.  This is normally the current date so the 01FEB15 would be '01' and the date would add the current month and year.

However, there are occasions when you need to enter the day for a date of no more than 3 days in the past.  This is not an issue if in the same month but if it for the end of the previous month it thinks it is the end of the current month.

So for example of on the 1st of the month I entered '30', this would be the 30th of the last month but this would only apply to no more than 3 days in the past, any other day would need to be in the future which is OK.

The time is then added from another text box called txtSTD.  This is then all passed to dtmSTD.

My code at the moment is;

```
    Dim dtmSTD = DateTime.UtcNow

    If txtSTD.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter an STD.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Me.Text)
        Return False
    ElseIf txtSTD.TextLength < 4 Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a valid STD.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Me.Text)
        Return False
    ElseIf txtSTD.TextLength = 4 Then
        If Not DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDay.Text & txtSTD.Text, "ddHHmm", Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, dtmSTD) Then
            MsgBox("Please enter a valid STD.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Me.Text)
            Return False
        End If
    End If
```

Any ideas would be appreciated?

Regards,

Andrew

Comment: Is this Visual Basic? If so, you should perhaps tag it as such.

Comment: It is VB.net, I have added a tag.

Comment: I would avoid such ambiguity and use something like a DateTimePicker or just require a valid date.  The user is not likely to appreciate such arcane rules.

Comment: It is the required this way, basically I just need to accept a day from the end of the previous month but it no that it is the end of the previous month and not the end of the current month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a function for my needs, it is below for other who may find useful.

It basically returns the date as a string and I can choose the return format.

If the date is outside of the allowed range (-2 / +1 days) then it returns a blank string.

```
Function SetDateFromDay(ByVal strdate As String, ByVal strReturnFormat As String, ByVal strTitle As String) As String
    Dim dteDate As DateTime = Date.UtcNow
    Dim strOutput As String = ""
    strdate = strdate.PadLeft(2, "0")

    Dim strLastMonth As String = dteDate.AddMonths(-1).ToString("MMMyyyy").ToUpper
    Dim strNextMonth As String = dteDate.AddMonths(1).ToString("MMMyyyy").ToUpper

    If strdate = dteDate.ToString("dd") Then
        Return dteDate.ToString(strReturnFormat)
    End If

    If strdate = dteDate.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd") Then
        If strdate > dteDate.ToString("dd") Then
            Dim strNewDate = strdate & strLastMonth
            Date.TryParseExact(strNewDate, "ddMMMyyyy", Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.none, dteDate)
            Return dteDate.ToString(strReturnFormat)
        Else
            Dim strNewDate = strdate & dteDate.ToString("MMMyyyy")
            Date.TryParseExact(strNewDate, "ddMMMyyyy", Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.none, dteDate)
            Return dteDate.ToString(strReturnFormat)
        End If
    End If

    If strdate = dteDate.AddDays(-2).ToString("dd") Then
        If strdate > dteDate.ToString("dd") Then
            Dim strNewDate = strdate & strLastMonth
            Date.TryParseExact(strNewDate, "ddMMMyyyy", Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.none, dteDate)
            Return dteDate.ToString(strReturnFormat)
        Else
            Dim strNewDate = strdate & dteDate.ToString("MMMyyyy")
            Date.TryParseExact(strNewDate, "ddMMMyyyy", Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.none, dteDate)
            Return dteDate.ToString(strReturnFormat)
        End If
    End If

    If strdate = dteDate.AddDays(1).ToString("dd") Then
        If strdate < dteDate.ToString("dd") Then
            Dim strNewDate = strdate & strNextMonth
            Date.TryParseExact(strNewDate, "ddMMMyyyy", Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.none, dteDate)
            Return dteDate.ToString(strReturnFormat)
        Else
            Dim strNewDate = strdate & dteDate.ToString("MMMyyyy")
            Date.TryParseExact(strNewDate, "ddMMMyyyy", Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.none, dteDate)
            Return dteDate.ToString(strReturnFormat)
        End If
    End If

    Return ""
End Function
```